# detect in which page a lightning web component is

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am making a lightning web component where its content is dynamic based on in which record page it is mounted to, example: if this component is added to contact record, it will display contacts, if it is added to Account record it should display Account.

Any idea how to detect in which record page the component is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce will automagically supply it to your parent component.  You will need to pass it to your child components as a parameter.

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class TestClass extends LightningElement {
    @api objectApiName;
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_object_context

Comment: If you are looking for record Type, there is a little more to it... but simply search for "LWC get record type by name" and you will get several code examples.  Thanks for the question, though it was a simple answer, I had forgotten that LWC would pass you more than just the recordId.